# Classes and inheritance

Tags: c++

I am new to OOP and I have encountered a problem while writing my first code. I do not understand why I can not use one class as a part of another. And no I do not want that class to inherit another. One of the requirements is that I prevent object copying.

```
    #pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Pilot 
{

public:
    Pilot(/*string x*/) 
    {
        setName();
        flight_hours = 0;
        set_status(0);
    }
    void setName(/*string x*/) 
    {
        cout<<"Unesi ime pilota: ";
        getline(cin,name);
    }
    string getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }
    void increase_flight_hours(int n) 
    {
        flight_hours += n;
    }
    int get_flight_hours() 
    {
        return flight_hours;
    }
    void set_status(bool b) 
    {
        status;
    }
    bool get_status() 
    {
        return status;
    }
    void display_pilot() 
    {
        cout << name;
        cout << "(", flight_hours, ")";
        if (status)
            cout << "-L" << endl;
        else
            cout << "-N" << endl;
    }

    Pilot (const Pilot&) = delete;
    void operator=(const Pilot&) = delete;

private:
    string name;
    int flight_hours;
    bool status;




};


#pragma once
#include"Pilot.h"

class Avion 

{
public:

    Avion ()
    {
        setName();
        set_capacity();
    }

    void setName(/*string x*/)
    {
        cout << "Unesi ime aviona: ";
        getline(cin, name);
    }
    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    void set_capacity()
    {
        cout << "Unesite kapacitet aviona: ";
        cin >> capacity;
    }
    int get_capacity() 
    {
        return capacity;
    }

    Pilot get_captain() 
    {
        return captain;
    }

private:
    string name;
    Pilot captain;
    Pilot copilot;
    int capacity;
};
```

I get this error :
`function "Pilot::Pilot(const Pilot &)" (declared at line 50 of "C:\Users\mjova\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Pilot.h") cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function   Project1    C:\Users\mjova\source\repos\Project1\Project1\Planes.h  36`

Comment: `Pilot get_captain() ` is a copy. You want `Pilot& get_captain() `

Comment: `using namespace` in a header is rude to everyone else who `include`s it.

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). TL;DR: never use `using namespace std;` in a header, in sources i cannot do that much harm, but still the downsides are more than the advantages

Comment: @ChrisMM rather `const Pilot& get_captain()`, as returning a non-const reference of a private member defeats the purpose of making it private

Comment: Construction should not interact with the user, and neither should setters (also, avoid setters when possible). Read the proper values outside and pass them as arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is here:

```
Pilot get_captain() 
{
    return captain;
}
```

which returns a *copy* of the captain, and you have expressly disallowed copying.

Return a const reference instead:

```
const Pilot& get_captain() 
{
    return captain;
}
```

(and don't try to copy what it returns).

There could also be some other copying-related code in "Planes.h"; it's not clear whether `Avion` is defined in that file or not.

Side note: since you can't copy `Pilots`, the `captain` and `copilot` members of `Avion` are problematic (you can't implement `set_captain`, for instance).
I suspect that you're going to want to change them to be pointers in the future, and let pilots exist without planes and vice versa.